# issue in use Coroutine in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

hi my dear friends......

I write follow class  for transparency a game object and Add As a component to several game object,But when i press play button ,All the objects that this class comes up with as a component starts turning on and off... If I want to just turn on the one game object that called by name......turn on and off.please help me
please.....

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Threading;

    public class Transparent : MonoBehaviour {

        private float duration =  .7f;
        public float waitTime;
        IEnumerator co;
         // Update is called once per frame void 
        public void Start()
        {
            this.co=this.blink();
            this.StartCoroutine (this.co);
        }
        IEnumerator blink() { 

            Color textureColor = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
                //textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration; 
                //this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = textureColor;
                while (true) { // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
                    // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
                    // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors


                    textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration; 
                this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor;


                    // reset the timer

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);



                }
            //end of if(this.transform.childCount =0)

        }

        void stop_Transparency () 
        {

                this.StopCoroutine (co);

        }

    }

and write different class for transparency dice that has child follow class

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dice_Transparent : MonoBehaviour {
    private float duration =  .7f;
    public float waitTime;
    IEnumerator co;
    // Update is called once per frame void 
    public void Start()
    {
        this.co=this.dice_blink();
        this.StartCoroutine (this.co);
    }
    IEnumerator dice_blink() { 

        Color textureColor0 = this.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor1 = this.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor2 = this.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor3 = this.transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor4 = this.transform.GetChild (4).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;
        Color textureColor5 = this.transform.GetChild (5).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color;

        //textureColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration; 
        //this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = textureColor;
        while (true) { // this could also be a condition indicating "alive or dead"
            // we scale all axis, so they will have the same value, 
            // so we can work with a float instead of comparing vectors
            textureColor0.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            textureColor1.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            textureColor2.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            textureColor3.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            textureColor4.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            textureColor5.a=Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, duration) / duration;
            this.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor0;
            this.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor1;
            this.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor2;
            this.transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor3;
            this.transform.GetChild (4).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor4;
            this.transform.GetChild (5).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().material.color = textureColor5;

            // reset the timer

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);



        }
        //end of if(this.transform.childCount =0)

    }

    void stop_Transparency () 
    {

        this.StopCoroutine (this.co);

    }
}
```

after start `coroutine` from every the above classes from anywhere on the program both `coroutines` Are executed........

I've called the component so that the test object points to a graphical object.

My call component :

```
test.gameObject.GetComponent<Transparent>().Start();
```

please help me....please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start()** is **Monobehaviours** reserved function, which executes by default when the script is enabled.
You can read about the Start function here: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html
If you want to call a function manually, then use other function name.
For example, copy the contents of your start function in a function named **MyStart()**, then call that function. Like this:

```
test.gameObject.GetComponent<Transparent>().MyStart();
```

Comment: @alikarimifard, I think the problem you are facing is all the coroutines are starting together, but you want only to start specific coroutines.
I couldn't understand anything more from the description of yours.
I provided solution according to it.
I can't understand, if you just say, "That's don't work." Please be more specific about the problem.